# can not compile after package keyword added

Tags: java, package

class A and B are independently save at the folder named "myjava", when i add the "package" at the first line, class B can not compile and prompt the following message but class A can compile sucessfully:

B.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
class B extends A{
^
symbol: class A
1 error

```
//package myjava;
class A{
  void funcA(){
  System.out.println("A");
  }
}

//package myjava;
class B extends A{
  void funcA(){
  System.out.println("B");
  }
}
```

i wonder why adding the keyword "package" can not compile successfully.

Comment: How are you trying to compile the code? If you're using `javac`, **exactly** what command and what working directory are you using?

Comment: Add some details on how are you compiling the classes . It might be the case that you are not including the class A (which is already compiled) in your classpath (by using -cp option if using javac).

Comment: [This][1] answer may be helpful to you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652899/difference-between-package-and-directory-in-java

Answer (score 0):

```
package myjava; 
public    class A{
 void funcA(){
 System.out.println("A");
}
}
```

--------------A.java--------------------

```
 package myjava;
 public class B extends A{
  void funcA(){
System.out.println("B");
}
}
```

----------B.java------------

Now compile

javac -d . A.java
javac -d . B.java

Hope this helps

Comment: I used the command as follow:
javac A.java   ---> can be compiled
javac B.java   ---> can not be compiled even have the "public" or without in front of "class B extends A"...

anyway thanks~

Comment: If your class having package you have to compile c:/> javac -d . A.java