# How to Properly Implement Packages in Java

Tags: java, package

I am learning how to use packages in Java, but I am running into trouble when trying to implement them. I have a simple class called Main which appears as follows:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        System.out.println("Package Test...");
    }
}
```

The directory of this class is: C:\Users\MyComputer\Desktop\Packages\Main.java

When I compile this class, I run into no trouble. However, when I add "package com.example.mypackage;" to the top of the .java file, compile the program, and try to run the program, I receive the following error: "Error: Could not find or load main class Main"

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: [Managing Source and Class Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html).

Comment: have you created the package or are you just mentioning the package name.

Comment: Are you using an IDE or command line `javac`? You need to also add the other packages and projects to your classpath.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12653042/8041461) may be helpful

Comment: I have only added the package name to the top of the .java file and compiled the program.

Comment: You have to create the package also. Create a pcakage, then piut your java file in that package, then run. It will run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the path of your class is `C:\Users\MyComputer\Desktop\Packages\Main.java` then your class is not in a package. In this instance "Packages" is your project folder, and it only contains the one java class.

If you want `package com.example.mypackage;` to work, then your path needs to be:

`C:\Users\MyComputer\Desktop\Packages\com\example\mypackage\Main.java`