# Wrong name error when class loaded from random dir

Tags: java, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I want to make a instance of .class file located into random directory. I tried this

```
private final String CLASS_FOLDER =
            "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\fix\\core\\src\\test\\org\\poc\\";

    private  Class getClassFromFile(String fullClassName) throws Exception {
        URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {
                new URL("file://" + CLASS_FOLDER)
        });
        return loader.loadClass("Order");
    }
```

When I run the code I get error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Order (wrong name: com/solutions/backend/toms/actions/Order)
```

Looks like a security check for correct package name. Is there nay way to skip this check because I need to load .class files into random directories?

Comment: not familiar with that error, but it might be the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509295/noclassdeffounderror-wrong-name

Comment: Yes this is the issue. Is there any workaround? Moving the .class file or making java -cp ... is not a option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Java classes need to be in a [directory hierarchy that matches their `package`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12652899/113632). You cannot drop a Java `.class` in a "random" directory, that's simply not how classloading works.