# Running java from command line with packages: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, command-line, package

I had a fully functional Java program that I am now trying to put into a package instead of having it in the default package.  All of the .java files are in the `mymap` package, and I am trying to run black box tests in my `MyMapTest.java` file.  The problem is that I don't know how to properly run this in the command line now that I have it in a package.  I got stuck trying to google for answers.

I can get it to compile:

```
javac -cp "../junit.jar" *.java;
```

But when I try to run it as I previously had...

```
java -cp .:../junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MyMapTest
```

I get the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mymap/MyMap` for all of my tests.  I guess the issue is that somehow I am not properly including mymap, perhaps in the classpath?

Similarly, I also have white box tests in `MyMapWhiteBoxTest.java`, where this file is also in the `mymap` package.  I cannot figure out how to properly run these tests either.  Trying to run it the same way, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyMapWhiteBoxTest (wrong name: mymap/MyMapWhiteBoxTest)
```

For both cases, I have tried `mymap/FILE` or somehow also including the package in the classpath, but I'm definitely missing something.

Comment: Possible Duplcate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951695/receiving-wrong-name-noclassdeffounderror-when-executing-a-java-program-from-t/12044735#12044735

Answer (score 0):

If the main() is present in MyMapTest class then you can try the below command :

```
java -cp .:../junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore myMap.MyMapTest
```

Comment: I tried that and JUnit says `Could not find class: mymap.MyMapTest`.

Comment: can you verify if MyMap.class is created ?

Comment: Yep, .class files are created for all of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

After compilation: (`javac -cp "../junit.jar" *.java;`) what do you have in your current dir? You should have the file ./myMap/MyMapTest.class.

Comment: I just seem to have MyMapTest.class

Comment: How is that? Do you have your source file into ./myMap/MyMapTest.java?
If you have ./myMap/MyMapTest.java, your compiled class must be ./myMap/MyMapTest.class

Comment: The mymap folder should contain the files in the mymap package, correct?  And MyMapTest.java is just importing mymap, so it shouldn't be in the mymap subfolder?

Comment: So this should work:
java -cp .:../junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MyMapTest

But if MyMapTest is declared in a package, you should run:
java -cp .:../junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore <mypackage.>MyMapTest

Comment: OK, I got MyMapTest to work.  I had something weird with the subfolders.
But I still can't get MyMapWhiteBoxTest to work. I try `java -cp .:../junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore mymap/MyMapWhiteBoxTest` and JUnit says `Could not find class: mymap/MyMapWhiteBoxTest`

Comment: in the current dir do you have **mymap/MyMapWhiteBoxTest.class** ?

Comment: No, actually.  Why would that not be compiling?

Comment: javac does not compile recursivelly. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623161/javac-option-to-compile-recursively

As pointed, you can do:
    `:: Windows`
    `> dir /s /B *.java > sources.txt`
    `> javac @sources.txt`

Comment: Thanks for that link.  I now have a mymap/MyMapWhiteBoxTest.class, but JUnit still says `Could not find class: mymap/MyMapWhiteBoxTest`

Comment: You have to run `java -cp .:../junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore mymap.MyMapWhiteBoxTest` and not `java -cp .:../junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore mymap/MyMapWhiteBoxTest` (see the '.' in the class name)

EDIT: start reading from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510932/java-package-vs-folder-structure-what-is-the-difference

Comment: Even better, start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html