# Could not find or load main class in java due to placing a package name

Tags: java

Before i create a package name to my class i done my work correctly. i faced problem like ** Could not find or load main class** after giving a package name to my class will you please check my below code

```
package c2.get.pack;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class FindDiff
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        arr.add(1);
        arr.add(2);
        arr.add(5);
        arr.add(5);
        arr.add(7);
        arr.add(7);
        arr.add(11);
        System.out.println("Prime number in ArrayList :"+arr);
        Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<Integer>(arr);
        arr.clear();
        arr.addAll(set);
        System.out.println("Prime number in Set :"+arr);
        Iterator itr=set.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
        int num=(int)itr.next();
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

i got an error result like this
first i compile the file with class name like

`G:\java\java_programs\logics>javac FindDiff.java`

after that had try to run the program with package name i give an error

`G:\java\java_programs\logics>java c2.get.pack.FindDiff
Error: Could not find or load main class c2.get.pack.FindDiff`

What the error here from my side.Please note that i used notepad to write a program.After compiling the program it's not create any package

Comment: Package hierarchy defines directory hierarchy. If your Java source says it's in package `c2.get.pack` then the file should be located at `../c2/get/pack/FindDiff.java`.

Comment: but here i cont find any package@DaveNewton

Comment: @TomK It again gives same runtime error

Comment: You still have to have it in the correct directory hierarchy even after making it public.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes i can find the .class with my file name but it's not wroking

Comment: Are you typing literally the exact thing Dave told you to?  Can you show us exactly what you're typing in your java command.

Comment: @sreeku24 if youre not using an IDE "java FindDiff.class" should actually work

Comment: @TomK it also gives an error, please check this,   "G:\java\java_programs\logics>java FindDiff.class
Error: Could not find or load main class FindDiff.class"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok. i copied your code and figured it out.
first compile everything with

```
javac *.java -d .
```

then the package, declared in FindDiff, will be created as folder structure and the .java files will be compiled into these

no you can run it by writing

```
java c2.get.pack.FindDiff
```

Comment: ""javac *.java -d.FindDiff.java"" i try to compile like it's not gives the result. Will you please tell me exactly

Comment: @sreeku24 Just write it as i did in the post, dont change the command!

Comment: G:\java\java_programs\logics>javac *.java -d .

G:\java\java_programs\logics>java c2.get.pack.c1
Error: Could not find or load main class c2.get.pack.c1

Comment: @sreeku are you sure that error came when you typed that command?

Comment: it's create the folders automatically in my root directory but i will try to run the second command what you mentioned there it's not working

Comment: sorry Tom it's working but instead of using this"G:\java\java_programs\logics>java c2.get.pack.c1" to "G:\java\java_programs\logics>java c2.get.pack.FindDiff"

Comment: Thanks for Helping @TomK

Comment: @sreeku24 sorry, i renamed the java file to c1 on my computer, the correct command is "java c2.get.pack.FindDiff"

Comment: Will you please change your answer "FindDiff" instead of "c1"

Answer (score -1):

The `FindDiff` class is not public, therefore the main method you have declared within cannot be taken as an entry point.

Make `FindDiff` public.

```
public class FindDiff { /* ... */ }
```

[Edit: further discussion and discovery of the problems in comments led to Tom K's answer, which solves the filename problems]

Comment: @sreeku24 Making it public (which is necessary) doesn't mean you don't need to put it in the correct directory.

Comment: You don't have to have a public class to run `main`.  In fact, you can have *several* non-public classes in the same file, each with their own `main`.

Comment: @DaveNewton, yes i make my class FindDiff as public and again it's gives same error like "Could not find or load main class c2.get.pack.FindDiff"

Comment: @sreeku24 I'm not sure how much plainer I can make it. You're compiling a Java file that's in your current directory. That directory does not match the package name contained in said Java file. The Java source must be located in a directory hierarchy that matches the package hierarchy. E.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/9510932/438992 etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton, i saved my file in G:\java\java_programs\logics

Comment: @sreeku24 Yes, I know; that's what I said. What I'm saying is that won't work, because it needs to be in `../c2/get/pack/FindDiff.java`, because Java.

Comment: @DaveNewton, program not generate folders directly

Comment: @sreeku24 ... Neat. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html

Comment: @DaveNewton, yes i understand what your saying. After creating the folders manually i got the final result