# Difference beetwen folder and Java Package

Tags: java

What's the difference between creating a folder and Java Package?

[image: Folder and Java Package Image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Package Vs Folder-Structure? what is the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510932/java-package-vs-folder-structure-what-is-the-difference)

Answer (score 0):

A folder is like you would use in a file explorer, it serves only as an organizational tool. A Java Package is the place where you design programs, it houses all types of classes, JavaDoc webpage code, and anything else that relates to the actual code. You need to use Java Packages, you only use folders for organizing said code and packages.